# Is there an easy way to check if CredSSP is enabled on a systems?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server, wsman

I am aware of the `Get-WSManCredSSP` function; however, this cmdlet does not work well in a script. This returns a long string similar to the following:

```
The machine is configured to allow delegating fresh credentials to the following target(s): wsman/*,wsman/*,wsman/*,wsman/*
This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.
```

I cannot easily include this in a script that I am writing, so I'm looking for an alternative way to check CredSSP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you consider using this as documented in the [CmdLet help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819468.aspx): Gets the WS-Management CredSSP setting on the client (`<localhost|computername>\Client\Auth\CredSSP`).

On a local machine it gives :

```
(Get-Item  WSMan:\localhost\Client\Auth\CredSSP).value
```

You can use it like this :

```
(Get-Item  WSMan:\localhost\Client\Auth\CredSSP).value -eq $false
```

You can first test if WinRm is available :

```
(Get-Service -Name winrm ).Status
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is for client enabled CredSSP.  If you want to check for server enabled CredSSP, use the following:

(Get-Item  WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\CredSSP).value

Answer (score 2):

I was also struggling with the limitations of the `Get-WSManCredSSP` output, and found [this helper script](http://blog.victorvogelpoel.nl/2014/03/03/powershell-get-wsmancredsspconfiguration-getting-credssp-configuration-for-local-or-remote-computers/) by Victor Vogelpoel/Ravikanth Chaganti to be really helpful.

Some examples:

Check if current machine has been configured as CredSSP server and/or client:

```
(Get-WSManCredSSPConfiguration).IsServer
(Get-WSManCredSSPConfiguration).IsClient
```

Check if a specified client machine has been set up for delegation:

```
Get-WSManCredSSPConfiguration | % { $_.ClientDelegateComputer.Contains('clientcomputername') }
```

Answer (score 0):

(not intended as a replacement for the work of Vogelpoel & Chaganti, but as a quick summary of a quick reading of CredSSP.cs, so you can get a quick grasp of what it's doing - that said, it was tested on several systems I had at hand and seems to work)

```
function Get-WSManCredSSPState
{
  $res = [pscustomobject]@{DelegateTo = @(); ReceiveFromRemote = $false}

  $wsmTypes = [ordered]@{}
  (gcm Get-WSManCredSSP).ImplementingType.Assembly.ExportedTypes `
  | %{$wsmTypes[$_.Name] = $_}

  $wmc = new-object $wsmTypes.WSManClass.FullName
  $wms = $wsmTypes.IWSManEx.GetMethod('CreateSession').Invoke($wmc, @($null,0,$null))
  $cli = $wsmTypes.IWSManSession.GetMethod('Get').Invoke($wms, @("winrm/config/client/auth", 0))
  $res.ReceiveFromRemote = [bool]([xml]$cli).Auth.CredSSP

  $afcPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentials'
  if (test-path $afcPath)
  {
    $afc = gi $afcPath
    $res.DelegateTo = $afc.GetValueNames() | sls '^\d+$' | %{$afc.GetValue($_)}
  }
  return $res
}
```